# How to fix delay of in-app messages on firebase for iOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm testing the Firebase in-app messaging on an iOS app. When I create a campaign, it seams like there is a delay to when the popup actually appears in the app (about an hour to an hour and a half). I want to find out if there is any way to fix this or if this is common. I cannot seam to find any answers to this currently available.

Comment: I'm using this feature about two months ago, and they works fine. But today i'm trying a campaign but it's working only on simulators.
It's very weird that in console i get the log `Running in simulator. Do realtime clearcut uploading.` or `Not running in simulator. Use regular clearcut uploading strategy.`for physical devices.

Maybe there's a different approach for one or other.

Comment: Sometimes i found other log: `No appropriate in-app message detected for display.`
I don't know what it means

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, can you help me?